# Problem with the proof of the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm reading the proof of the Open Mapping Theorem from "Analysis Now", by Pedersen.

**Theorem:** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T\in B(X,Y)$ with $T(X)=Y$, then $T$ is an open map.

The proof goes like this: We can write $Y=\cup\bar T(B(0,n))$, where $B(0,n)$ is the closed ball of radius $n$ around $0$. Now, by the Baire category theorem we can say that there exists $n$ such that there is $B(y,\epsilon) \subset \bar T(B(0,n))$. This means that $T(B(0,1))$ is dense in $B(y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$, and therefore ... (it continues but we arrived at the point that I don't understand).

How do we know that $T(B(0,1))$ is contained in $B(y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$? I know that, because $B(y,\epsilon) \subset \bar T(B(0,n))$ then $B(n^{-1}y,n^{-1}\epsilon) \subset \bar T(B(0,1))$.

EDIT: It can be worth noting that in the proof, the author invokes a Lemma (2.2.3.  in the book):

***Lemma 2.2.3.*** If $T \in B(X,Y)$ and the image of the unit ball in $X$ is dense in some $B(0,r) \subset Y, r>0$ then $B(0,(1-\epsilon)r) \subset T(B(0,1))$, for every $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Maybe it should be $T(B(0,1))\cap B(y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$ is dense in $B(y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$?

Comment: I thought about this. But as the proof continuous, after showing the above "density", invoking a lemma (2.2.3) which asks for the density of $T(B(0,1))$ is some ball. (I am writing it as an edit in my question).

Comment: Also, every time you wrote $B(y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$ should have been $B(n^{-1}y,n^{-1}\epsilon)$ instead.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I edited my argument on one inclusion using your suggestion, but I left what I took from the book as it is written, so that we can hopefully make a clear reasoning about what is written and what we have to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this might be a case of poor wording. The usual proof of Lemma 2.2.3 in fact proves a little bit more. We have

> **Lemma:** Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a normed space with $T \in B(X,Y)$. Suppose that there exist $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and $r > 0$ such that for any $y \in B(0,r)$, $\operatorname{dist}(y, T(B(0,1))) < \varepsilon$. Then $B(0,r(1-\varepsilon)) \subseteq T(B(0,1))$.

The usual proof of the OMT then proceeds by noting that since $T(B(0,1))$ is convex and symmetric about $0$, $B(n^{-1}y, n^{-1} r) \subseteq \overline{T(B(0,1))}$ implies that $B(0, r) \subseteq \overline{T(B(0,1))}$.

In particular, since $B(0,r) \subseteq \overline{T(B(0,1))}$, the lemma gives us that $B(0,r(1-\varepsilon)) \subseteq T(B(0,1))$ for every $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and so 
$$B(0,r) = \bigcup_{\varepsilon \in (0,1)} B(0,r(1-\varepsilon)) \subseteq T(B(0,1))$$
which implies that $T$ is an open mapping.